# One button with 2 actions

Tags: winforms, powershell, button, click, action

I did try to make 1 button that makes 2 actions: one on the 1st press (click), the other on the 2nd press (click), and repeat. However, none of my approaches worked for me, so I made 2nd button to make 2nd action, but I would really like to have only one. Here is small example that should help you help me :).

```psh
#This creates the all button and sets the event
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,20)
$OKButton.Text = "all"
$OKButton.Add_Click({
  $ua2Checkbox.Checked=$true;
  $nvsCheckbox.Checked=$true;
  $krsCheckbox.Checked=$true;
  $uaCheckbox.Checked=$true;
  $hbrCheckbox.Checked=$true;
})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})

#This creates the none button and sets the event
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,20)
$OKButton.Text = "None"
$OKButton.Add_Click({
  $ua2Checkbox.Checked=$false;
  $nvsCheckbox.Checked=$false;
  $krsCheckbox.Checked=$false;
  $uaCheckbox.Checked=$false;
  $hbrCheckbox.Checked=$false;
})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
```

---

```
$actionAll = {
  #$ua2Checkbox.Checked=$true;$nvsCheckbox.Checked=$true;$krsCheckbox.Checked=$true;$uaCheckbox.Checked=$true;$hbrCheckbox.Checked=$true;
#$OKButton.Add_Click($ua2Checkbox.Checked=$true;$nvsCheckbox.Checked=$true;$krsCheckbox.Checked=$true;$uaCheckbox.Checked=$true;$hbrCheckbox.Checked=$true;)
#$OKButton.Remove_click({$ua2Checkbox.Checked=$false;$nvsCheckbox.Checked=$false;$krsCheckbox.Checked=$false;$uaCheckbox.Checked=$false;$hbrCheckbox.Checked=$false;})
}
$actionnone = {
 #$ua2Checkbox.Checked=$false;$nvsCheckbox.Checked=$false;$krsCheckbox.Checked=$false;$uaCheckbox.Checked=$false;$hbrCheckbox.Checked=$false;
#$OKButton.Add_Click($ua2Checkbox.Checked=$false;$nvsCheckbox.Checked=$false;$krsCheckbox.Checked=$false;$uaCheckbox.Checked=$false;$hbrCheckbox.Checked=$false;)
#$OKButton.Remove_click({$ua2Checkbox.Checked=$false;$nvsCheckbox.Checked=$false;$krsCheckbox.Checked=$false;$uaCheckbox.Checked=$false;$hbrCheckbox.Checked=$false;})
}


$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,20)
$OKButton.Text = "all"
$OKButton.Add_Click({invoke-expression "$actionAll"})
$OKButton.Remove_click({invoke-expression "$actionnone"})
#$OKButton.MouseDoubleClick({$ua2Checkbox.Checked=$false;$nvsCheckbox.Checked=$false;$krsCheckbox.Checked=$false;$uaCheckbox.Checked=$false;$hbrCheckbox.Checked=$false;})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to toggle the action of the button each time the button is clicked, you need to replace the current action with the other action within each action:

```psh
$actionAll = {
  # other operations here
  $OKButton.Text = 'None'
  $OKButton.Remove_Click($actionAll)
  $OKButton.Add_Click($actionNone)
}

$actionNone = {
  # other operations here
  $OKButton.Text = 'All'
  $OKButton.Remove_Click($actionNone)
  $OKButton.Add_Click($actionAll)
}

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Text = 'All'
$OKButton.Add_Click($actionAll)
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
```

Comment: excuse me my stupidity but i'm unable to make it working... :(

Comment: i tried this way and it is not working for me, maybe I'm doing something wrong :(     $okbutton.Remove_click don't do anything, don't know why

Comment: @filbrinza Where in my sample code do you see an `Invoke-Expression`? There also isn't a `Remove_Click()` outside the action scriptblocks. Please do not get creative.

Comment: I tried your code as first and it didn't worked for me, thats why I tought i'm missunderstanding something and tried with some modifications of your code to be sure it didn't work.....

Comment: Try without the additional curly brackets in `$OKButton.Add_Click({$actionAll})`.